# DataBind not happening with ClientTemplate in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am having a Kendo grid. I am trying to render another grid inside a grid column cell. When I load the page, the main grid is loaded, but the grid within the cell is not getting data. Below is my code for Grid in my cshtml page.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Sales.OrderDetails>()
    .Name("Orders")
    .Events( e => e.DataBound( "onGridDataBound" ) )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Category).Title("Category");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Title("OrderDate Date").Width("10%");
        columns.Template(p => "").Title("").ClientTemplate(
            Html.Kendo().Grid<Sales.ProductDetails>()
            .Name("Orders_#=ID#")
            .Columns(c =>
            {
                c.Bound(r => r.Name);
                c.Bound(r => r.Amount);
                c.Bound(r => r.Quantity);
            })
            .AutoBind(true)
            .DataSource(dataSource1 => dataSource1
               .Ajax()
               .PageSize(200)
               .Read(read1 => read1.Action("GetProductDetails", "Sales", new { OrderID = "#=ID#", area = "Sales" }))
            )
            .ToClientTemplate()
            .ToHtmlString()
        );
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow:auto; height: 600px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Pageable(page => page.Refresh(true).Input(false).PreviousNext(true).Numeric(false).Info(true))
    .Sortable()
    .NoRecords()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.Category))
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrderDetails", "Sales", new { area = "Sales" }))
    )
)
```

I have below DataBound JavaScript code also

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onGridDataBound(e)
    {
       $('#Orders script').appendTo(document.body);
    }
</script>
```

I am not able to find out why the child grid in the clientTemplate is not getting data. Its coming as empty

Comment: Is it hitting the controller? No console errors?

Comment: It is not hitting the controller. No console error also.

Comment: Show the GetProductDetails method. Make sure it has parameters named `OrderID` and `area`.